# What Happened Here? Voted to Close 4 Days Ago, but No Close Votes Today?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, specific-question

Today I saw "[Test to see if User/Pass entered for a WebService are correct or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187923/test-to-see-if-user-pass-entered-for-a-webservice-are-correct-or-not)", realized it was a duplicate and voted to close it.

I then saw in the comments that I had voted to close it four days ago!

How did *that* happen? There were no close votes listed at all, and I was permitted to vote to close it today!

Comment: Nice, a question about close votes, which itself is closed, and is linked to from the SO documentation on close votes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We now use a form of sliding expiration, so as long as close/reopen votes keep arriving **at the rate of at least one every 4 days**, they will not expire.

Once the votes do expire, vote aging happens every 24 hours, so you can expect the remaining very old close/reopen votes to expire at the rate of 1 per day after that, *unless of course someone casts another close/reopen vote* in which case the expiration timer resets to 4 days.

Also, if the question has <= 100 views, <s>no expiration on close (or reopen) votes is done at all</s> [as of March 2015, close votes still expire as above, but the required rate is reduced to one per 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting).

Comment: The bit about [`Close votes age away harmlessly after 4 days if the threshold is not reached.`](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) on the privileges page is now slightly wrong.

Comment: Would it make sense to apply the same sliding window expiration to comment flags?

Comment: Quick question: Is this just a more advanced version of the original system? I thought that close votes were all wiped after a few days already

Comment: @sarnold no, I don't think so, because comment votes are pushed into the moderator flag review queue and I can't imagine them surviving for more than a day, tops, before being handled

Comment: Would it be sensible to change the views count to be n views since the current vote started?

Comment: Is this rule applied in all SE communities?

Answer (score 7):

Close votes age away after 4 days if the question is not closed, according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583).

Comment: I never realized that. I guess I haven't seen such obvious duplicates remain open.