# Why is the close vote review queue so full?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

There can't be over 50k current close votes. [Close votes expire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions):

> Close votes age away harmlessly **after 4 days** if the threshold is not reached.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433679/how-to-increase-mysql-fetch-array-pointer) for instance [is in the close vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1148590). It has no visible close votes when I open the question which means the close votes aged away.

But why is that question still in the review queue? It should be removed.

Comment: It's come down from over 57k when the new review queues were first launched. I'd say it's working. Don't forget you are have limits to the number of close votes you can cast and it needs 5 people to agree, so it's going to take time.

Comment: It is not working any more. The number is rising a while now and at 54k at the time. It has been down to 47k some day in the past.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The queue is full of items that have close votes but not yet have 100 views. Close votes only expire if the post has had enough views; see the [What Happened Here? Voted to Close 4 Days Ago, but No Close Votes Today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594)

The queue also includes items that were *flagged* by people that not yet have the reputation to vote to close themselves. If you do not yet have [cast close votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) but do have the [flag posts privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) you can request that a post be closed through the `it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate` option. In that case you will not see any close votes when it appears in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Items in the review queue are not necessarily there for their close votes. It's possible for a question with flags, or maybe even a question with older close votes to appear on the queue. Also, questions automatically detected by the system, probably also appear there.