# 5 years of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, participation

I noticed Stack Overflow will become 5 years old soon.  Not sure of the exact date though.

Are there any plans for the site to celebrate its 5th birthday (no idea what - special site features?)?

Either way I would like to use this post to say thank you to the Stack Overflow team for the last 5 years of helping me learn.

---

Thanks to the comments:

Private beta began on July 31, 2008, but the site wasn't public until Sept 15

So it will be 5 years soon

Comment: I thought SO were much older... It accumulated so much information in only 5 years? amazing...

Comment: One word:  **Stickers**

Comment: Private beta began on July 31, 2008, but the site wasn't public until Sept 15.

Comment: I feel most answers are "what can SO give us". I suggest we think about what we can do for SO.

Answer (score 71):

We could change the logo for the day:

[image]

Comment: Needs more unicorns. And preferably the `5` should be drawn in red using MS Paint.

Comment: Nicely done.  Alternately could put a 5 in the overflowing paper bin.

Comment: Maybe get rid of one of the pieces of paper so there's only 5

Comment: @LBT: We'll save that for Meta.SO's 5 year anniversary.

Comment: Guys, **we're not celebrating 5 years of Meta.SO!** It's *Stack Overflow* that's having a birthday.

Comment: @NathanOsman EXACTLY! What do we do for Meta?

Comment: Oh, Stack Overflow.... then who cares?

Comment: `we're not celebrating 5 years of Meta.SO!`  Not with that attitude, we're not :P

Comment: @NathanOsman [Aren't we?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GNzpG.png)

Comment: @Cole: No, Meta.SO is [a good 9 months](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/) younger than SO itself.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know. I made that just because I have nothing else to do. My votes and comment votes ran out today 3:

Comment: I see lens flare. Was your version of the logo directed by J.J. Abrams?

Comment: @Jin: Nope, it was directed by [this guy](http://docs.gimp.org/nl/images/using/wilber.png) :P

Comment: @LBT [I tried](http://i.imgur.com/aA9pJXl.jpg)

Answer (score 14):

Give everyone 5 days worth of hats?

Comment: Unalloyed genius. I am spellbound by your enlightenment.

Comment: How many hats would that be? One per day?

Comment: _One per day_, @StephenTG?! Don't you change your hat before lunch, at tea, after dinner, when leaving work, and as you sit down to supper?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Naturally! I'm no barbarian!

Comment: +1 for hats. Since hats have been used before, the software to give hats is (presumably) already in place.

Comment: @S.L.Barth There were hats before?! What could have possibly caused them to remove them?

Comment: @StephenTG It was a temporary event: http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash .

Answer (score 10):

Those are proposals for StackOverflow team:

1. Give everyone 5 rep for free (the easiest to made)
2. Give everyone, who logs in the anniversary, a special souvenir badge
3. Start 5 foreign language proposals, 4 of them already waiting, 5th (Russian) is almost done (if I believe they'll do that, I should believe also in unicorns, but whatever...)

Comment: Only 5 rep? 5 years is 1825 days; I much prefer that (or 157680000 seconds).

Comment: @Matt 157 billion milliseconds :P but that would probably make our rep overflow to a negative number or something :P

Comment: You don't believe in unicorns?

Comment: @Doorknob, the English 157,000,000,000 is even still much smaller than JavaScript's max integer 2^53 or 9,007,199,254,740,992 (which often is the first to cause issues, as [it is not really an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)) -- so that shouldn't be a problem. Even when interpreting 157 billion as 157,000,000,000,000 we're still fine. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Well,

### Greedy!!!

Stackoverflow T-shirt for 55 people. People are chosen randomly or by any selection method based on letter 5 -  like people have reputation in all 5's at the start of the day (like 55 ,555, etc). Or give it to 55 people who get more reputation through the day(without considering rep cap).

### Not so greedy

Any special hat/badge for 55 people. They can wear them for 5 years, until 10th birthday. They need to give it back on 10th birthday.

### Happy!

A big cheers for SO in the morning, and a happy birthday banner hanging on top throughout the day. And then just another day at the **Office**.

### Grumpy!!

No vote limit for the day and automate a help vampire question every 10 minutes, through out the day.

> Hi all, My team lead (#@$@#$) want me to prgm a HTML5 websit in C
>   without usng any editor othr than ms paint. Pls Gve me the codz.

so that everyone do some real moderating.

Happy Birthday Stackoverflow!!

Comment: Don't agree with the automatic spamming, but unlimited close votes would take care of [another problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/when-was-the-number-of-questions-with-close-votes-to-review-0-on-stack-overflow)...

Answer (score 1):

Quintuple everyone's reputation?

Comment: That would be *far* too easy a way to earn rep... but we could write the rep in base-5 instead of base-10, and get a similar effect :-)

Comment: Perhaps quintuple all rep at the start of the day, then quintuple all rep gains, losses, and privilege thresholds?

Comment: Jon Skeet's rep is _obscene_ in base-5: 122,242,202.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Implying it isn't obscene in base 10...