# How long should I wait before developers implement feature request?

Tags: discussion

Do developers have to implement upvoted feature request?
How long should I wait before developers implement feature request?

Comment: @JohnPalmer 6 to 8 weeks is more common.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do developers have to implement upvoted feature request ?

No. The community team looks at these and decides which ones should be implemented. Some feature requests that are highly voted may actually be detrimental to the site (performance, actual goals of the Stack Exchange network or other reasons) and will be declined.

Some are good ideas, but may take a while to figure out properly (requests that appear simple may actually have subtle issues that need to be ironed out).

> How long should I wait before developers implement feature request ?

6-8 weeks.

Seriously though - once a feature has been decided as one that should be implemented, it needs to be designed, agreed on and of course implemented. Sometimes that can take 5 minutes, sometimes 6 months. Depends on the scope of the change.

Comment: And sometimes [over three years](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) :P

Comment: @Doorknob - Sometimes it can take that long for the community team to decide a feature is worthy (see how neatly the dev shifted blame to someone else?)

Comment: Three years ago, didn't "the community team" consist of Jeff Atwood?

Comment: @Oded - What happened to http://sixtoeightweeks.com/? :(

Comment: @hims056 yeah, noticed that too!

Comment: But none had yet taken more that 5 years: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190421/5-years-of-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

> Do developers have to implement upvoted feature request ?

No. There are lot of feature requests that are upvoted, but status declined.

> How long should I wait before developers implement feature request ?

It depends on the task and many other factors. You could be better served by specifying which feature request you have made.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that a feature request will be implemented, no matter [how many votes it has.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined?sort=votes)

It is completely up to the dev team. It sometimes takes than a day, and sometimes [over three years.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)