# Why don't we have "Need Info [from OP]" status?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Every time I try to browse new questions trying to find something I can help with, I always end up with too many questions left abandoned by OPs: community requested clarification/more details, and OP never came back to reply.

This suggests a simple solution similar to bug tracking software, where ticket can have "Need Info" status when the product team can't proceed with it until more info is given from the ticket author -- and can be easily skipped when browsing the list.

Design of this feature for SO could be plain simple:

1. Anyone who left a comment to a question can mark the question as "Need Info" (implying "there's a consensus among those who responded already that the question can't be responded until more info is provided")
2. While question is in NeedInfo, comments and answers can be still added
3. Anyone (including the original poster) can mark it back to Open, even without adding any further information to the question

Comment: How do you answer a question if there's not enough information? That sort of implies that it's unanswerable, no?

Comment: And if you push animuson's thoughts a bit more, you get the close process we already have.

Comment: Such questions should be closed as "*off-topic*" -> "*Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**.*". And when OP add required information, you can reopen it.

Comment: @hims056 no. "lacks code" or "unclear" seems more appropriate here.

Comment: @JanDvorak - We can use either unclear or the one I have suggested. "Need more info" == "lack of minimal understanding".

Comment: The community is out here to *help*.  If the OP doesn't post information to let community help her, so be it.

Comment: @animuson Where I said that I answer a question before there's enough information?

Comment: @Mat Where I said that I answer a question before there's enough information?

Comment: @yurkennis: your point 2 implies it. If the question needs info, it's not properly answerable.

Comment: @Mat I would allow that someone who marked NeedInfo may be not knowledgeable enough and miss some way of solving question that is still exists.

Comment: @yurkennis: that's already what happens with close votes. The question stays answerable until 5 people (or a mod) agreed that it isn't sufficient for whatever reason. That's why 5 votes are required: there needs to be a bit of consensus that the question is lacking before it's marked as "needsinfo" == on hold.

Answer (score 12):

We have this. It's closing a question with a reason "Unclear what you're asking" (or perhaps off topic reasons "Show research and attempted solutions" / "Share your code").

Comment: Then why so many questions do not get closed as such, and stay open for years? Maybe the UI should make these options more outstanding?

Comment: @yurkennis There's a queue for close votes, and it's pretty backed up (see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/what-can-be-done-about-the-massive-close-votes-queue-on-stack-overflow?lq=1)). Questions *are* getting closed, just not as quickly as they're being marked.

Comment: @DennisMeng From the post you've linked to, isn't it clear that the current process needs a revisit, as it's stuck in a bottleneck of few very experienced community members? And only 1% "pending close" (as a ratio in current 5,824,306 questions) look too little to me, it feels more like at least 10% of questions are worth closing as NeedInfo while still open.

Comment: @yurkennis: what's the point of "closing as needs info" if that status does nothing (doesn't prevent answering) and even the OP can clear the status without doing anything?

Comment: @Mat The point is to make life easier for experts who are the scarcier resource compared to askers. Via early seeing NeedInfo questions in the Unanswered list. If OP bothered to clear the status, it is still some effort - I believe most of currently abandoned questions won't be touched by OP with status reset either.

Answer (score 3):

I like the basic idea because "needs more information" is much more motivating than "Unclear what you're asking". The former is a direct call to action, while the latter just says "your question sucks". I have seen users who believe they can't edit a question while it is closed; that the question is lost once it reaches that state.

The "instant reopen" idea is interesting, but would bring too many problems from OPs choosing the option with no clue what they were supposed to fix. Still, it seems like a step in the right direction. Perhaps we could make reopening under this close reason  *easier*? Say instead of five reopen votes, require only one or two.

Answer (score 0):

NeedInfo seems unnecessarily vague, when we have the following two off-topic close reasons:

- Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.
- Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

To answer your final point (emphasis added):

> Anyone (including the original poster) can mark it back to Open, **even without adding any further information to the question**

Re-opening the question even though nothing has changed is not something we trust the OP to do, for the obvious reason they are/could be simply ignoring the 5 high-rep users who decided the question should be closed/off-topic. To re-open the question needs to go through the re-open queue (and 5 high-rep users need to agree to re-open), ideally after the OP or someone else has addressed the closers' concerns.