# How many questions in the close queue have not been viewed in the last week?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Given:

- The close queue is very large and not much progress is being made.
- A bad question that no-one sees is not a real problem

So how many of the questions in the close queue are not being seen by anyone?

Also can we somehow predict how likely a question is to be viewed in the next week and only include questions in the close queue when they are likely to be viewed soon?

Comment: This suggestion would result in part of the VTC queue being hidden, which is not the right way to deal with the problem IMHO. If you want to go down that route, why not get rid of the entire queue once and for all?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi,If people thought that by doing reviewing they were doing something more worthwhile, then more people would do reviewing.     Once say questions that are expected to be view in 1 day are under control, the window can be increased to questions that are expected to be viewed in 2 days and so on.

Comment: @Ian, yes, I see this reasoning quite often. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208694/164403) is my personal take on why that unfortunately won't work.

Comment: It may be that we should have two close queues,  “Full close queue” and “close queue for questions people are hitting from Google.”

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, The only **value** in closing questions is to stop people spending time trying to answer them, and to make it less likely that other questions like it will be asked.     As far as I can see, a bad question that is not being viewed does very little harm.  A pile of bad questions that is rotting away in a **unseen** room does not smell, unlike pizza boxes.   (We also have a unlimited number of unseen rooms to use.)

Comment: @Ian, depends. I imagine "not being viewed" actually means "viewed by less than X users in Y amounts of time". Even if only a few users see the question, shouldn't we still aim to prevent them from wasting their time on it?

Comment: @AlienArrays
Agree, but if they believe that they are making a dent in a smaller but more important problem….  (Just look at how fast “new posts” are processed)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi,  It takes at least 5 (high rep) people spending time to close a question so is the effort worth it if only say 1 person is likely to view the questions in the next 3 months?

Comment: @Ian, IMHO yes, but my opinion doesn't really matter here. Let's reverse the problem: I was under the impression that highly-visible questions would be closed without the need for a queue (since they're viewed by a lot of users). The queue was introduced to deal with questions that should be closed but are not viewed enough for the "normal" closing process to take place. I'm at a loss to determine a threshold between this and "questions viewed so rarely closing them does not matter anymore".

Comment: Maybe it is the questions that are hit often from Google, but not by hi-rap SO users that are the real issue.