# New top bar is not an improvement in usability

Tags: discussion, top-bar, design

Besides the many questions/complaints below about appearance and style, I'm really just not seeing how this is in any way a streamlining of the old top bar. It seems like everything takes at least 1 and sometimes 2 extra clicks to get to.

Personally, I think it looks really nice (except the envelope/inbox image does not look like an envelope so much as the back of a station wagon), but it's just really inconvenient to use.

In particular, needing to click "StackExchange" to get to "Chat" and "Log out" really bugs me.

Anyone in agreement on this?

Comment: I really wonder how many threads we need about this topic

Comment: its not an envelope, it is an inbox

Comment: Apart from cheese being moved, do you have something specific you find inconvenient to use, over the old bar? That is, outside of a rant/complaint, do you have anything constructive to add?

Comment: Yeah...there's a lot of space up there. Maybe try putting "Chat" and "Log out" and "Meta" back in the main set of links.

Comment: @psubsee2003 isn't that what I said? And what exactly does an inbox look like?

Comment: With the previous top bar, you either had to wait for the panel with the *log out* link to appear, or click the tiny arrow, so I don't see how this has changed.

Comment: http://discretionarydollar.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/inbox.jpg

Comment: @psubsee2003 The image in the bar looks nothing like that. OH WAIT I SEE IT

Comment: @Aerovistae the same thing happened to us on meta.  There was an ah-ha moment when we saw what it looked like

Comment: @Aerovistae: your question is not clear about what you're waiting for, you're asking for direct links to "Chat" and "Log out" but the first 2 paragraphs are just personal experience.

Comment: @Aerovistae: that has already been proposed in other posts here on Meta; this makes your post a dupe.

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how a meta, which is about discussing opinions, can get sometime closed as "primarily opinion-based". But that's probably just me.

Comment: \*shrug\* I like it, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Advantages of the new bar

Access to site switch, inbox and notifications are all 1 click less than previously. As highly used actions this is highly useful.

Rep notifications are now shown (my favourite part of the new bar)

### Disadvantages of the new bar

Log out and chat are one click further away, however, these are (in my experience) less regularly used functions than site switch, inbox and notifications so I consider this a fair trade.

Meta is also one click further away; however, it is more consistent for it to be with the other sites. Additionally; I used the meta link a lot, but I believe I am a-typical in this and the meta links was also rarely used; again justifying moving it off the top bar

### Conclusion

As with all change there are pros and cons, however I believe the pros outweigh the cons

Comment: You are not atypical and are definitely not alone.

Comment: -1 You are very different from me. I never clicked "review" or "help". I click "meta" and "chat" couple times a day.

Comment: @tohecz We want people [to click review a lot lot more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/what-can-be-done-about-the-massive-close-votes-queue-on-stack-overflow), putting it out of sight would basically doom the site. Equally I was careful to look at this from what the "average" person would do. Do you think meta is importent for 99% of our visitors? You seeing my post at all is selection bias because you are already on meta

Comment: @RichardTingle I hit review whenever there's something to review. Isn't that enough? And what about a customizable menu? Simple checkboxed or multi-combo would work for this. Damn this is 21st century!

Comment: @tohecz I don't understand what you mean. I'm not saying you're wrong not to review, just that we need people to, so we need to make it as visible to review as possible. I see you're not a heavy stack overflow user where the major close review queue problem is (100,000 questions in the queue and rising)

Comment: @RichardTingle In that case, it's much more visible and much likely for people to click on it, when it appears _only when you want them to click on it_. Maybe on SO, there's always something to review. But on the other sites, you have maybe one review per hour, or even one review per day. However, you don't seem to be active on any average site to recognize this, hence you don't see my perspective. So this might make sense on SO. However, it's ridiculus and stupid on other sites. Therefore, I would prefer to opt out of the useless button and opt in to my `chat` and `meta` rather.

Comment: @tohecz Where did I argue against it being customisable? But that is a separate discussion for a separate feature request

Comment: @tohecz Probably true, but the majority of users are on the 3-4 largest sites. So if there is no customisation then ultimately it's a greatest good for the greatest number situation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/661/discussion-between-tohecz-and-richard-tingle)