# Which is more common: rep cap on meta, using all close votes, or ...?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, behavior

There are a number of behaviours common to those who want to make SO better. Each of them carries a "you've done all you can today" achievement with it:

- Post questions or answers on Meta that are well received --> rep cap on Meta some days
- work the SO review queues --> run out of close votes some days (the other queues never have enough in them for me to use my votes, but if someone does I'm impressed)
- Vote on questions and answers on any non-Meta site --> use up votes some days
- flag content --> use up flag limit some days

I may be missing a "janitor" behavior; edit one in or suggest it in the comments and I will.

Of these, which is more common? On a random day, will more people hit the rep cap than use up their close votes?

Comment: `the other queues never have enough in them for me to use my votes`. I **always** exhaust my votes reviewing suggested edits.

Comment: You're a better unicorn than me. I can't spend long in suggested edits before I get ticked off and go do some work

Comment: Today I used all my close votes and all 100 of my flags, yet I didn't hit the rep cap. This is pretty common for me, especially since I haven't been answering many questions lately. I'm sure it varies upon the user. Tons of people hit the cap consecutively.

Comment: Of those I am more likely to rep cap. I feel more inclined to answer questions than to browse around voting or take it in the face by the SO review queue.

Comment: The system refuses to let me use all my close votes for the day. :(

Comment: @KateGregory Well maybe because thats the only fun review queue my rep allows me to access. :)

Comment: @animuson hmm... you could go for top all time reviewer... do 104,324 close vote reviews.  I mean, Bill has *only* done 15.4k reviews all time.  You could be on the top of the list **forever**.  Think of the notoriety!  "He's the guy who did 103k in one day reviews before going insane... Pity he couldn't finish them all"

Comment: I'd prefer using all flags, but sometimes stop flagging since I can't handle the issues completely due to running out of needed close votes.

Comment: Not sure what's your goal here? Random poll, or looking for actual official details of all users? Personally I'm with Meta Rep Cap and sometimes consuming my suggested edit reviews limit on SO when bored enough. :)

Comment: While on the review topic, has anyone noticed that the number going into the SO queue has jumped from an average 184 per day to well over 1000 per day?

Comment: If someone knows how to do it on Data Explorer that would be great.

Comment: @KateGregory - I have an excel spreadsheet with 30 entries in it spanning over 9 months. It came mostly from [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183840/178816) and from observing the queue size daily since I realized (about a week ago) the acceleration in the queue (started roughly 4 weeks ago).

Comment: I don't really see how this would be useful, either. It could be argued that hitting the rep cap is a vastly different type of activity than reaching the close vote limit. Some (albeit few) users can hit the cap with no activity at all.

Comment: I consider clearing the queues and getting stuff either closed or not-in-close-process a good thing. Some people say "give us more close votes" and I wonder, do we need more? Are we using them all? I'm not. And why aren't I, when I do other things to the limit and beyond all the time? And since I'm not necessarily representative, I came to wonder whether in general people use up their votes, and if so whether it is more common or rarer than hitting other limits.

Comment: also @Pëkka I don't mean the SO rep cap which is entirely different. I mean only the meta rep cap. Different action but same motivation (and, I wager, people.)

Answer (score 8):

Don't see the point of this, but... In the past 30 days on Stack Overflow:

- 77 people have earned at least 200 points in a single day on MSO a combined total of 165 times.
- 1,060 people have reviewed at least 20 tasks in at least one queue OTHER THAN CLOSE on a single day, for a total of 6,977 review-capped user-days.
- 253 people have reviewed at least 40 tasks in the close review queue on a single day, for a total of 1,335 close-review-capped user-days.
- 669 people have cast at least 30 votes in a single day, for a total of 1,965 vote-capped user-days. (note that you can cap out at 40 if you vote on enough questions; I'm not trying to figure out how many people did this.)

Perhaps more useful: [prolific editors](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=quarter), [frequent voters](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter)

Comment: So this tells me one of the reason the close vote queue keeps growing is less people are willing to chop at it. Even the cap-hitters hit an average of 7 times a month for the nonclose and 5 times for the close, and there are way less caphitters for the close queue. Doesn't seem like more votes would help, to me.

Comment: No, raising the vote-cap would probably not do much of anything for the backlog, @Kate (I actually thought I posted that particular statistic in response to one of the proposals for that change, but can't find it now).

Comment: @Kate - In my opinion, it is hard to get to the low hanging fruit in the close vote review queue. To me, it seems like all I get are hard ones. Questions from today that I try to salvage (some of which are changing while I examine them), instead of questions from last week that would be easier to make a decision on.

Comment: @Travis closing a question from last week, while useful, is much less useful than closing a low quality question that was just asked because the OP is likely still around to improve it

Comment: (Reposting because I realized I wasn't 100% clear the first time) Thought about posting as a full answer, but seems more like an add-on to this; given the low-density of questions in general (at least compared to SO), it occurs to me that hitting the rep cap is almost never more common than something else for people *in general*. An individual might hit the rep cap more often, but that's the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @RichardTingle - Why is that? The low quality post that was just asked is getting attention from places other than the queue and will be closed rather quickly. The low quality post asked last week is getting no attention. The new post has a higher percentage to be salvaged because the OP is closer to it in time. The older post has a lower percentage of being salvaged because the OP is further from it in time. In a month the older post will be *buried*, and the unfortunate part is that it will gain strength in searches the longer it stays around. Why is it "much less useful" to close?

Comment: @TravisJ, try filtering to a tag that has under 1000 questions, then once you have emptyed the queue for that tag, choose anther tag that overlaps it.

Comment: @IanRingrose - I am done closing questions from the queue. It is a broken feature and in my opinion represents a certain hypocrisy given that now poor questions are just supposed to be downvoted and moved on from.

Comment: Well, I reach the close limit every single day, and I cannot even close half of the bad posts that I see, even within my expertise area. That is sad for SO to lose valuable contribution.

Comment: @KateGregory 7 times a month is not little. It might mean 100 % of their weekend days, for instance. Maybe there's a significant subset of users who would work through the review queues during their weekends if the cap were higher. Or maybe you're right, but this number definitely doesn't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your goal here, but it *appears* to be a straw poll. So here's my response:

I tend to use up my close votes most often, with flags a close second.

Answer (score 0):

If any of these, I will hit the meta rep cap most frequent.

It is hard to hit the review cap for some of the groups in SO like suggested edits because often the queue is empty.

I think I hit the close vote cap once. It is just that when I review the close votes I really try to salvage them and it can take a long time for certain worthy posts.

I can't remember the last time I hit the upvoting daily limit, I don't browse around all that often.

I probably use 2 flags a week.