# Is a closed question without any other votes in four consecutive days still possible to reopen?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I have asked a question:

- [What is the Type? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573292/what-is-the-type)

It has been closed and might not have any casting vote changed in the past four days.

Before I ask this meta question, I have read

- [What Happened Here? Voted to Close 4 Days Ago, but No Close Votes Today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today)

But I didn't get it. I'm confused with that is a closed question without any other casting vote in four consecutive days still possible to be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All** closed questions are able to be nominated for reopening.

You can't see a re-open vote link as you don't have sufficient rep to cast close/re-open votes on your own questions - [the requirement is 250](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) on graduated sites including Stack Overflow.  Confusingly this privilege is named 'View Close Votes' but works as I describe.  Other users [require 3000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) to cast close or in this case re-open votes on your question.

Your question was closed as too localised (five people voted to close it):

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Which means that the community doesn't think that your question is likely to be helpful to other people in the future.  It is not related to the title you chose.  If you would like to get your question re-opened, then the correct way to do this is to edit your question to be applicable to a wider situation that others may face (though reading the comments on your question **this may not be possible**).  Once edited your post goes into a review queue where users with the close/re-open privilege may decide to re-open it as appropriate (again five votes are required/one moderator vote).

The meta question you link to refers to people casting close votes on other's questions.  In the past, these would start to age away if they didn't reach the five vote threshold (though I believe this behaviour has been modified by the introduction of the new review queues).  Either way, this isn't an issue you're having.

You may find the following FAQ entries helpful to read:

- [What is a "closed" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)
- [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

<sup>* Locked questions are different to closed questions - these can not have re-open votes cast on them</sup>

Comment: Aging still works as described; the queues supplant the minimum # of views requirement for aging to happen at all.

Comment: @Shog9: Would you describe your comment in some simpler sentences? I can't read it..

Comment: @Shog9 does that mean the 100 views requirement has gone though?

Comment: I think he means that the review queues will give the posts the required views faster.

Comment: @Ken, I've tried to go into a bit more detail [in an answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124) - let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm reading it. If further I have more question, then I would ask with a post. Thank you very much!