# Reopen vote count not showing

Tags: bug, vote-to-reopen

I am trying to reopen the closed question but I am trying to do then it displays the message "You have already voted to reopen.." but see in the screenshot question does not show reopen vote count. I think this should show here like also **reopen(1)** and it does generally but not for me.

[image]

Comment: I believe reopen votes expire over time. When did you vote to reopen this question?

Comment: I did on Dec 17 2013

Comment: Your vote then has indeed expired. It takes only four days for votes to expire if a matching vote has not been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reopen votes [expire after 4 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594) if no more reopen votes are added, but you only ever get to vote *once*.

You've already voted on that post, but your vote has since expired.

Comment: You might want to add a note that votes do not expire if the question has not received at least 100 views.

Comment: @JoshMein: Perhaps, but that's more detail than is required for answering the OPs direct query. The linked post explains that. Clearly, the post the OP voted to reopen *does* have more than 100 views.