# The information on close-votes aging mechanism in Help Center is out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, help-center

Network-wide Help Center on [Cast Close And Reopen Votes page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) *still* says

> Close votes age away harmlessly after 4 days if the threshold is not reached. Each new close vote resets the timer, and close votes only start expiring [if the question has had 100 views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594).

Recently [we have rewritten close votes aging mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250453/260672). Aging votes and flags starts after 14 days, regardless of view count. So the information on that page **is out of date** and needs to be updated.

Comment: Looks like animuson fixed this... uh, back in December of '15